# Can a TypeScript definition file have a require statement?

Tags: typescript

Is it legal in my definition file (.d.ts) to have a statement like...

```
import foo = require('some-module/bar');
```

I thought that would immediately turn my definition file into a module.  However, this code also works for me if I don't have `strict` mode turned on.  This is TypeScript version 3.7.5 if it matters.

Comment: If you need to use a import inside your d.ts file you can always split them into multiple files (global.d.ts, something.d.ts), where you keep global.d.ts globaly scoped. I used a similar technique for providing overrides for redux Dispatch and works like a charm.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit, why you expect the statement to fail?

Comment: @ford04 I thought declaration files had to be types and constants.  `require` doesn't seem like a very constant statement to me.  For example, when is the `require` evaluated?  Is it during compile time or during runtime?  I didn't think `require` ran during compile time and I didn't think declaration files were used during runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is, you are mixing up TS [`import = require()`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require) with the [`require`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/f4e58f2e65ccf8552f6372acff796398009a36d3/types/node/globals.d.ts#L191) function from Node.JS.

The former is a special import notation syntax used by TS to offer CommonJS module imports, accompanied by `export =` from the dependency side, usable in `.d.ts` files.

The latter is the global Node.JS `require` function, whose types are obtained via `@types/node`. You indeed wouldn't be able to put this in a `.d.ts` file, as statements are not allowed in ambient contexts.

In general, `.d.ts` files may contain import statements of type declarations from other files, these are usually relative module imports from the project. And they only matter during compile-time, as [types are erased](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) at run-time.

Comment: This matches what I've been seeing.  The type system was treating it as an `import` of sorts and just importing the types from the `.d.ts` files of the `some-module` module.  Then at runtime it was compiled down to a `require` statement that was executed as normal.